# Triangle-free graph with chromatic number >= 4 and one vertex of a color

Tags: graph-theory

I was wondering about the existence of an example of a graph in the title - ie a triangle-free graph which is not 3-colorable such that one of the colors only colors one vertex. The Groetzsch graph needs at least 2 of each color as far as I can tell. I would prefer an example which is 4-colorable.

Any ideas on how to find such a graph other than a brute force computer search? My understanding is that although the Groetzsch graph is the smallest triangle-free graph which is not 3-colorable it does not necessarily imply that a larger graph cannot have the property I'm looking for.

Comment: Just to clarify: are you asking for a triangle-free graph which is not 3-colorable, but in which there is a vertex s.t. when coloring this vertex with a 4th color the remaining graph is 3-colorable?

Comment: yes, and the graph should be triangle-free

Comment: In that case I think the Groetzsch graph should work. If you color the unique vertex of degree 5 with the fourth color, the rest is 3-colorable. In fact, a smallest triangle-free graph that is not 3-colorable must necessarily work: if you would need to color two vertices with the fourth color, you could just remove one of them to get a smaller graph which is still triangle-free and still not 3-colorable, contradicting the minimality.

Comment: Ah, it does indeed work! Thank you